# Append string to textarea on click using js

Tags: javascript

When pressing `Add foo`, the textarea get's filled with string: `foo`.

However, after typing something in my textarea, my `Add foo` button doesn't work anymore.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('content').append('foo \n\n')">Add foo</button>

<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input elements, you can use `+=` to append to the value.

**Here is a cleaner version**

```js
content = document.querySelector("#content");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
   content.value += " ADD FOO";
});
```

```html
<button>Add foo</button>

<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

**Here is a version using your code**

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('content').value += 'foo \n\n'">Add foo</button>

<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since textarea is a form element, you should append to its value attribute:

```js
function addFoo(){
  let ta = document.getElementById('content')
  ta.value += 'foo \n\n'
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addFoo()">Add foo</button>

<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the content of your element then add what you want

```
<body class="flex justify-center items-center bg-purple-700">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('content').value=document.getElementById('content').value+'foo \n\n'">Add foo</button>

<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
```